# Use Spring @RestController without implicit @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, spring-webflux

My controller looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@RestController
public class MainController
{
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

the "test"-String I return is the filename of a Thymeleaf-template that should get processed. Instead, just "test" gets shown, when I access the page. I've read that `@RestController` implicitly does a `@ResponseBody` on all its mappings. But how can I prevent that? Or should I simply use `@Controller`?

Comment: not sure what you meant by "does a @ResponseBody on all its mappings". You should use `@ResponseBody` if you want it to process your thymleaf template

Comment: @pvpkiran how am I supposed to process a Thymeleaf template with `@ResponseBody`? The code above works perfectly (searches for a "test.html" in resources/templates and processes it with thymeleaf) when I just use a regular `@Controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### @RestController

This annotation is to deal with webservices, it's all about data, presentation markup such as HTML doesn't have any role here.

### @Controller

This Annotation is what you want to use if there is a `view` involved. `view` can be anything which will spit out an `html` (with or without interpolating the `model`). You can use good ol' JSP, JSF or templating engines like freemarker, thymeleaf, velocity etc as a `view`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct `@RestController` will always produce `ResponseBody` on the methods. you will need to use a standard `@Controller` to return templates or views.
A `@RestController` is specifically designed to be used for RESTful web applications and the `@Controller` for MVC web applications.